# Viewing ASP.NET errors on a Headless Linux System running Mono

Tags: asp.net, mono

I'm developing an asp.net application on windows 7 visual studio 2010, then publishing it to a Headless (NO GUI) linux server which runs mono.

I'm getting the error that tells you viewing errors from a remove machine is not possible unless you do some magic on the web.config.
[image]

Usually, i remote desktop into the server and load the page so i can see the error. But in this case since the server is headless i cannot do that. I don't really feel like doing a wget or curl... I just want to pull up the error in a browser. **HOW CAN I DO THAT?**

I've tried doing what the error message says and this is what my current web.config looks like:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am uncertain as to why the change to web.config doesn't work, it certainly looks correct.

Are you able to install firefox on the headless server?

If so you could run an X server on your development machine (like XMing) and forward the xsession over SSH

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similiar (developing on Win7 .Net and deploying to Amazon Linux). An easy way to see the full error message is to install Lynx (a lightweight text-based web browser) on your linux server, and then browse to the troublesome page locally! It works for me anyway! :-)

Comment: (+1) i tried going this route, but for some reason (maybe because i'm ssh'd into ssh into ssh kind of thing) i can't get it to work. But i would have liked this to work for me. However, i decided to go lynx because the server only has 1GB RAM and i'm trying to keep it as light as possible. Thanks anyway.